# Meteor template helper conditional returns false consistently

Tags: node.js, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

Im very new to Meteor but so far Im really enjoying coding on the platform. I have come up against a bit of hurdle and cant seem to find the correct way. I want to create a helper function that will check lat and long and check it against some predefined range if it falls in between these it returns true.

I have included the code I currently have:

```
Template.header.helpers({
 locationCheck: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback,error_callback);

    function success_callback(p){
        // Building Latitude = 51.522206
        // Building Longitude = -0.078305
        var lat = parseFloat(p.coords.latitude);
        var lon = parseFloat(p.coords.longitude);
        console.log('Latitude: '+lat);
        console.log('Longitiude: '+lon);

      if( lat >= 51.521606 && lat <= 51.522606 && lon >= -0.078805  && lon <=  -0.077705 ) {
        console.log('you are in the area');
        return 1;
      } else {
        console.log('you are not in the area');
        return 0;
      }
    }

    function error_callback(p){
         return 0;
    }
 }
});
```

And in my template I want to use the return value in a handlebars if statement, like so:

```
  {{#if locationCheck}}
        {{loginButtons}}
  {{else}}
        <p>Your are out of the vicinity</p>
  {{/if}}
```

The problem is it is consistently return the else statement result even though in the console it is returning this `you are in the area`.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the callback pattern. The helpers would have already returned undefined by the time the callbacks return data. You need to use synchronous javascript inside helpers, and if having an asynchronous operation use [reactive](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) Meteor `Session` [hashes](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) to relay the data through:

```
Template.header.helpers({
    locationCheck: function() {
        return Session.get("locationCheck");
    },
    isLoading:function() {
        return Session.equals("locationCheck",null); 
    }
});
```

Then in your header when the template is [created](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created) you can fire the check off:

```
Template.header.created = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback,error_callback);

    function success_callback(p){
        // Building Latitude = 51.522206
        // Building Longitude = -0.078305
        var lat = parseFloat(p.coords.latitude);
        var lon = parseFloat(p.coords.longitude);
        console.log('Latitude: '+lat);
        console.log('Longitiude: '+lon);

      if( lat >= 51.521606 && lat <= 51.522606 && lon >= -0.078805  && lon <=  -0.077705 ) {
        console.log('you are in the area');
        Session.set("locationCheck",1);
      } else {
        console.log('you are not in the area');
        Session.set("locationCheck",0);
      }
    }

    function error_callback(p){
         return 0;
    }
}
```

As soon as `Session.set("locationCheck",1)` (or `0`) is set the template will be re-rendered with the new data.

You can use the `isLoading` helper while its capturing the location:

```
<template name="header">
    {{#if isLoading}}
    Loading
    {{else}}
        {{#if locationCheck}}
            {{>template1}}
        {{else}}
            {{>template0}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="template0">
    <p>Denied</p>
</template>

<template name="template1">
    Approved
</template>
```

Comment: That seems to be working great, just for clarification is it possible to pass arguments so I can render a loading template before it is set?

Comment: I added another `isLoading` helper you could use to display a message while its acquiring co-ordinates

Comment: Ahh that seems to have done the trick. If you look at the `getCurrentPosition` function you will see there are 2 outcomes success and failure how do I return a different template depending on the whether it has been accepted or denied.

Comment: Edited the answer with how to do this too. You can use {{>template}} to put in the content of another template