# Can't access Meteor.user() in Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to write a simple method that will return the email (or any other field) of a logged in user. I have autopublish turned off but whenever I try to access Meteor.user() in my displayField method I get undefined.

However, if I write a general function (outside of Meteor) it can access it and display it fine... what am I doing wrong??

```
Meteor.methods({
displayEmail: function () {
 var user = Meteor.user();
 if (!user)
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, "you need to be logged in");
 console.log(user.emails[0].address);
 return user.emails[0].address;
}
 });
```

My client side function:

```
Template.hello.greeting = function () {
 var output = Meteor.call('displayEmail', function(error,id) {
 if (error) 
   return alert(error.reason);
 });
 return output;
 };
```

My template:
       `...`
      `{{greeting}}`
      `...`

So like I said, the console.log(user.emails[0].address) works just fine, but I get a blank in my template...

Comment: Could you post your code and what version of Meteor you are using?  This works fine for me on 0.6.6.3.

Comment: Your call to `Meteor.call` is asynchronous which is why `output` is null.  The email address you are looking for is available in `id` in your callback. To get it into your template, take a look at these similar questions w/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540328/meteor-template-helper-conditional-returns-false-consistently and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632050/meteor-return-asynchronous-function-to-handlebar-template.

Comment: I had a feeling it had something to do with that... do you have any links to read up on with regards to asynchronous/synchronous?

Comment: [Meteor docs section](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call_). You can google around for stuff like "javascript asynchronous callback patterns".  Heres an SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19083385/2359560) that has some good explanations.  As you read more about callbacks and asynchronous programming, you'll run into terms like "callback hell" and ways to get around them using things like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and Promises.  Perhaps its good to keep in mind that one of the cool things about Meteor is that it lets you do asynchronous things as if they were synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

With autopublish off, you would have to actually publish the user in order to access that data.

Autopublish would automatically publish it for you, but is generally a bad idea for production usage.  When you turn it off, you have told Meteor that you will handle all of the publishing necessary.

Example:

```
Meteor.publish("currentUser", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

Comment: well this is weird.. I have autopublish off and I have no Meteor.users publish or subscribe activated but if I go console.log(Meteor.user()..) in my Meteor.methods it will show.

Comment: The `accounts-base` package publishes the current user (only username, emails, and profile fields) regardless of autopublish. It auto publishes other users if the autopublish packages is used. See [lines 562-635 here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L562).

Comment: but why can't I return the user email from the method? I can get it to console.log from the method but I can't get it to output in my client function...

Answer (score 0):

Just answering my own question, so go-oleg is correct, with an async call you need the callback function in Meteor.call to get the variable back.

So my Meteor.call part should look like:

```
Meteor.call('displayEmail', function (error, result) {
   Session.set("displayEm",result);
 }); 
 return Session.get("displayEm");
```

In other words, the callback function needs to set a Session variable (which is reactive). The 'return' on the Meteor.method is the 'result' of the callback function (basic JS, I know).